# Visual Studio 2022 Git context menu does not appear anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

All,

In the previous version of VS (19) was a lovely source files context menu that could provide basic git operations like "blame", "compare with unmodified", "commit", etc. But in new VS 22 version git context menu completely disappeared.
[image]

I have feeling it was deleted.
Does anyone know the good replacement of this feature? Any extension that provides a git hub context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see it does not appear in my screenshot above.
However, after I installed a plugin:
[image]
Context menu started to appear:
[image]
when I disabled the plugging, git context menu continue to appear:
[image]
probably plugin installation reset settings of the context menu.

@jessehouwing, thanks anyway.

Comment: You didn't have the menu bar visible in this screenshot in the question, so I wonder if the Git menu was even present at the time. If Visual Studio didn't have a source control tool set yet, installing an extension specifically for Git might have triggered that happening.

Comment: I did not have the git hub items in the context menu, but git was installed and source control was active. I've done a few commits so far. the only change was installation and disabling of the "git extension" extension.

Answer (score 28):

For Git menu not showing:
In VS 2022, go to Tools > Options > Source Control.
Change to Git if not selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This option I verified first.  git was selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's going on in your v Visual Studio 2022. Mine has a Git context menu at the bottom of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue and seems to be specific to .json files.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-menu-in-context-menu-is-missing-in-json-files/1537530

Still not fixed in 17.1.2 :(

Answer (score -1):

try this:
In solution explorer- right click on the file name
Choose git->Blame/annotate is visible
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVdwD.png)

Comment: Context menu does not appear at all.
This is the problem.
Please read the title.